# Xcode 7 Beta 2 crash when trying to run UI test

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to test the new UI Tests with XCode 7.
Here's the test I wrote:

```
func testExample() {
        let app = XCUIApplication()

        let field1TextField = app.textFields["Field 1"]
        field1TextField.tap()
        field1TextField.typeText("test")

        let xcuiSecureTextField = app.textFields["_XCUI:Secure"]
        xcuiSecureTextField.tap()
        xcuiSecureTextField.typeText("test2")

        app.buttons["Log In"].tap()
    }
```

When I'm trying to run the test Xcode builds the project, succeeds and when it moves to the "Testing" phase it crashes.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Report a bug to Apple; Xcode should never crash.

Comment: @RoboticCat Ha, good one.